# "No model config found in the file at <tensorflow.python.platform.gfile.GFile object at 0x000001BBB233A990>"

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jMNf.png)
Please help me to solve this problem.

I trained this model through 8 different pre-trained models. I tried upgrading the TensorFlow and Keras library versions, retraining the model, changing the path of the model, renaming the model, and importing libraries in different ways. Still trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you saved with model.save or model.save_weights?
Also, try to provide a working example so that we can see if it's a bug.

Comment: use `model.save('model_weights.h5')` will work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm still getting this issue and the suggestions here are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

First, use save command to save your tensorflow model in .h5 file (Tensorflow version 2.15.0): `model.save('path/model_name.h5')`

Then use this code to load your model:

`model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path/model_name.h5')`

Then do not forget to compile it, for example like that:

`model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=l_rate))`

Kind regards,
Yevhenii